# Django: If value exists in database, pass it as a variable from view to template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-3.0

I am new to coding and new to Django. I searched stackoverflow for my question but didn't find what I was looking for:

What I am trying to do is check if certain values are in my database and if yes, pass it as a variable to the template. The values will be items of a dropdown menu.
If I have for example a database with bicycle1 to bicycleN I'd like to check if the value of the attribute "handlebar" of each database-object matches a certain manufacturer. If yes, pass it to the template so it can appear in the dropdown menu to later filter the results.

First I thought I should check in the template itself and thought about something like this:

**bicyle_list.html**

```
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
      {% for bicyle in bicycles %}
          {% with manufacturerA=False %}
            {% if manufacturerA == False and bicycle.handlebar == "manufacturerA" %}
                <li><a href="#!">ManufacturerA</a></li>
                {% manufacturerA=True %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endwith %}
      {% endfor %}
```

But as I understand the template should only contain rendering logic. (Besides, I`d have to use boolean variables in the for-loop, because a manufacturer should only appear once in the dropdown menu even if there are several bicycles with that certain handlebar. Changing the value of variables in a template seems quite complicated to me.)

In the views.py I thought about this but don't know how to work with conditions and the rendering-method:

**views.py**

```
        bicycles = Bicycle.objects.all()
        for bicycle in bicyles:
           if bicycle.handlebar == "manufacturerA":
               manufacturerA= "manufacturerA"
           if bicycle.handlebar == "manufacturerB":
               manufacturerB= "manufacturerB"

#if variable manufacturerA exists, pass it to the template – if not, not! Same with manufacturerB
#But how to include in return render(..)?

        return render(request, 'shop/bicycle_list.html', {'bicycles': bicycles})
```

Do you have any idea how to pass optional variables?

Comment: So basically you want a list of `handlebar` values from the `Bicycle`s?

Comment: Yes, exactly, a list of values that i'd like to access in the template to use as a dropdown menu - but every value just once even if it appears more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain a list of distinct manufacturers with:

```
def some_view(request):
    manufacturers = Bicycle.objects.values_list('handlebar', flat=True).distinct()
    return render(request, 'shop/bicycle_list.html', {'manufacturers': manufacturers})
```

```
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  {% for manufacturer in manufacturers %}
    <li><a href="#!">{{ manufacturer }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You however might want to make a model for the manufacturer, and work with a [*many-to-one relationship* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the answer to my question!